# My Gallery Won't Display Previously Saved Images

Tags: gallery

I'm usually one to give advice on Android-related questions, but one of my friends asked me a question I really didn't know the answer to. She said that she saved an image to her Gallery yesterday, and later that night she was looking through them. Today, the images aren't there. Any ideas on where they could have possibly gone? She said to save the images she just clicked "Save."

Comment: Where did she click "save"? Is this in some app?

Comment: She used Gmail, I assume because she said she e-mailed them to herself prior.